# SwiftUI - ForEach Loop in code is not displaying on tab

Tags: swift, list, foreach

In my `.tabItem 3` my loop is not displaying in the preview. Am I missing something? Still learning swift...

```
            .tabItem {
                VStack {
                    Image(systemName: "gamecontroller")
                    Text("Tab 3")
                    VStack {
                        List{
                            ForEach(0..<100) { index in
                                Text("This is tab 3!")
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `ForEach` is inside the `.tabItem`, which is the tab bar icon. There's no way that tiny button can display 100 items.

I assume you want the `ForEach` to be that tab's screen?

[image: Tab 3 active, showing 100 rows of 'This is tab 3!']

Just put the `VStack` before the `.tabItem`.

```
VStack {
    List{
        ForEach(0..<100) { index in
            Text("This is tab 3!")
        }
    }
}
.tabItem {
    VStack {
        Image(systemName: "gamecontroller")
        Text("Tab 3")
        
    }
}
```